# Dataframe write to JSON as single object

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that I am trying to write out to an S3 location as a JSON.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = false)
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Email: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- UserFoodFavourites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- foodName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isFavFood: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- UserGameFavourites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Department: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- gameName: string (nullable = false)
```

Writing out dataframe to JSON:

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("mode","append").json("s3Location")
```

JSON output I get:

```
       {"userId":111,"firstName":"first123","address":"xyz",
         "Email":["def@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"],
         "UserFoodFavourites":[{"foodName":"food1","isFavFood":true},{"foodName":"food2","isFavFood":false}],
         "UserGameFavourites":[[{"Department":"Outdoor","gameName":"O1"}],[{"Department":"Indoor","gameName":"I1"},{"Department":"Indoor","gameName":"I2"}]]}
       {"userId":123,"firstName":"first123","address":"xyz",
         "Email":["def@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"],
         "UserFoodFavourites":[{"foodName":"food1","isFavFood":true},{"foodName":"food2","isFavFood":false}],
         "UserGameFavourites":[[{"Department":"Outdoor","gameName":"O1"}],[{"Department":"Indoor","gameName":"I1"},{"Department":"Indoor","gameName":"I2"}]]}

alias prettyjson='python -m json.tool'
```

However this does not work when I try printing this file in a pretty JSON format using prettyJSON on this file because these are written as multiple JSON objects per `userId`.

I am trying to write this out as a single JSON object with new line separation, so I can run prettyJSON on this file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Each userId should be newline separated. Spark writes the JSON data in such a manner that each row of the dataframe stays in a single line. I didn't get the part "also these are not new line separated"

Comment: I double checked and yes they are new-line separated but not in a format that can be pretty printed.

Comment: The pretty print requires a single JSON for printing. In Spark multiple JSON is written in a single file, all separated by a newline. So unless Pretty Print can handle that, I doubt you would be able to use it for JSON display.

Comment: So what is the best way to print JSON file that is written out by spark with multiple objects, in a pretty format?